# Issue with Swagger when deploying to AWS Beanstalk - Node.js - Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, swagger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying [this app](https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-mongoose-boilerplate) to Beanstalk of which the underlying EC2 instance uses Node.js v12 and Nginx.

When the app is run at my localhost, **swagger docs** is rendered normally as expected.

But when deploying to Beanstalk, the result is `timeout`
The reason, as I've been inspecting until now, is that all of the accompanying *resource files* are loaded from *https* protocol, which is not available at Beanstalk server, while the source *index.html* is loaded from *http* protocol.

Note that the protocol my beanstalk is *http*, as you could see from the screenshot.

[image]

Related source code

- [swaggerDef.js and swagger.yml](https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-mongoose-boilerplate/tree/master/src/docs)
- [routes.js](https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-mongoose-boilerplate/blob/master/src/routes/v1/index.js)

Thank you for any helps!

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you manage to get around this?

Comment: Not yet. The docs hasn't been hosted there yet :(

Comment: Were you able to get an answer to this? Please post it.